# Paypal express checkout, How to not use session for send value between SetExpressCheckoutPayment and DoExpressCheckoutPayment?

Tags: php, session, paypal

Paypal express checkout, How to not use session for send value between `SetExpressCheckoutPayment` and `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` ?

Now in `SetExpressCheckoutPayment` process i will set session value for use in `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`.

EG:

```
$_SESSION['ItemName']           =  $ItemName;
$_SESSION['ItemPrice']          =  $ItemPrice;
$_SESSION['ItemNumber']         =  $ItemNumber;
$_SESSION['ItemDesc']           =  $ItemDesc;
$_SESSION['ItemQty']            =  $ItemQty;
$_SESSION['ItemTotalPrice']     =  $ItemTotalPrice;
$_SESSION['TotalTaxAmount']     =  $TotalTaxAmount;
$_SESSION['HandalingCost']      =  $HandalingCost;
$_SESSION['InsuranceCost']      =  $InsuranceCost;
$_SESSION['ShippinDiscount']    =  $ShippinDiscount;
$_SESSION['ShippinCost']        =   $ShippinCost;
$_SESSION['GrandTotal']         =  $GrandTotal;
```

But i don't want to use session, How can i other way except หำหหรนื ฦ

Comment: Sorry, would like to help but I am confused by your question. I suspect we do not share the same primary language, but can you clarify what you mean by "not use session" and what information you are trying to carry through which steps of the process?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid session variables you could save the data in a database table temporarily and then pull it back out when you return from PayPal in order to populate the DoExpressCheckoutPayment request.

You could also do the same thing with a log file of some sort.